# Why am I offered Nvidia driver 440 for a GTX 550?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

The latest driver for my GTX 550 is 390, but since 20.04 Ubuntu offers me version 440. Why?

440 is not compatible with the card.

Answer (score 0):

It will often offer you the newest stable version. For myself it took some time to get version 384 running smoothly so I decline all newer versions. It's better with the devil you know than the devil you don't know.

Comment: From my experience it will only offer the latest compatible version. 440 is not compatible. I will clarify that in the question. 19.10 correctly did not offer 440, but 20.04 does.